# Proving a function is in the double dual space [proof verification]

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I just want to double check that this proof is okay. Recent assignments have left me questioning almost everything about my math knowledge.

## Here's the question:

For each $\mathbf{v} \in V$, define the function
$$ \mathbf{v}^*:V^* \to \mathbb{F}, \qquad \varphi \mapsto \varphi(\mathbf{v}).$$
Show that $\mathbf{v}^* \in V^{**}$, where $V^{**} = (V^*)^* = \mathcal{L}(V^*, \mathbb{F}).$

## My proof:

We note that since $V^{**} = \mathcal{L}(V^*, \mathbb{F})$, we must simply show that $\mathbf{v}^* \in \mathcal{L}(V^*, \mathbb{F})$. Consider $\varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in V^*$, and $k \in \mathbb{F}$. We have:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{v}^*(k\varphi_1 + \varphi_2) 
&= (k\varphi_1 + \varphi_2)(\mathbf{v}) \\
&= (k\varphi_1)(\mathbf{v}) + (\varphi_2)(\mathbf{v}) \\
&= k\varphi_1(\mathbf{v}) + \varphi_2(\mathbf{v}) \\
&= k\mathbf{v}^*(\varphi_1) + \mathbf{v}^*(\varphi_2)
\end{align*}
Hence we have shown linearity of $\mathbf{v}^*$ as required.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your proof other than some minor notation things but that's left to the reader

Comment: Noted. I have done my best to clean it up.